# Use Regex Replace to add a character at specific location in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string something like this

```
Material TD Vandal High Supreme Signal Blue / University Red-B
```

I want to add hyphen, so final string becomes

```
Material TD Vandal High Supreme Signal - Blue / University Red-B
```

Hyphen should be added word before first `/`
string can have multiple `/`

i tried `string.replace(/([A-Za-z][ ][/])/g, '-$1');`

tried few more things, but nothing is working.

Comment: Try `.replace(/[A-Za-z]+\s+\//, "- $&")`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i3mrPP/1)

Answer (score 2):

When you say *Hyphen should be added word before first `/`*, the question is why did you use `/g` modifier? `g` means "global", it will try to find all non-overlapping occurrences of the regex match in the string. You do not need that modifier in the first place.

Second, `[A-Za-z]` matches a *single* char. Since the regex engine matches strings from left to right, the letter that is matched with this pattern should be followed with a space and then a slash, hence, it will match `e /`, not `Blue /`. To match a whole word, you will need to add a `+` quantifier after `[A-Za-z]`. You might also just use `\w` if you do not care if those are letters or digits (or `_`). Even `\S+`, one or more non-whitespaces will work.

To keep it close to the original, I suggest:

```
var result = string.replace(/[A-Za-z]+\s+\//, "- $&");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i3mrPP/1).

**Details**

- `[A-Za-z]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\/` - a `/` char (escaped because it is used in a regex literal).

The `$&` in the replacement pattern is the replacement backreference that refers to the whole match, no need wrapping the whole pattern with a capturing group.